# How to put EditText info into a Intent variable

Tags: android, android-intent, methods, subactivity

I'm trying to get the user information typed in the edit text. I want it saved into the `Intent` result variable. Trying to sending it back to the main activity afterwards. Keep getting the cannot resolve method. I'm thinking it must be that I'm missing a parameter in the `putExtra()` method

```
public class EnterDataActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enterdata);

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_done);
    final EditText getData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_data_here);


    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent result = new Intent();

            result.putExtra(getData);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
            finish(); // Ends sub-activity


            }//ends onClick
        });
    }//ends onCreate void button
}
```

Comment: You cannot put a widget into an extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are trying to send the `EditText` **that's not possible**.

If you are trying to send the text that are on that `EditText` **that's possible**.

### How to do it?

Declare a `String` to save the data (You can avoid this step, but that's more clear)

```
String mText = getData.getText().toString();
```

Then you'll use the [`getExtra() method`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) to send the `String` to the new `Activity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("text_from_editText", mText);
startActivity(i);
```

Then the last step (You don't ask for it, but you'll need it), get the text.

```
//onCreate() of the second Activity
Intent i = getIntent();
String mText = i.getStringExtra("text_from_editText");
```

Comment: Thank you also. That last part I will definitely as I need to execute it as a toast

Answer (score 0):

Replace `result.putExtra(getData);` with  `result.putExtra(getData.getText().toString());` to get the text from the EditText. Right now you're trying to put the entire EditText object into the intent as an extra instead of just the text from the EditText.

Comment: Thank you!! Now that makes sense

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your issue, please accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark on the left